# Marketing cloud Email - Call back times - Add to Calendar

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, calendar

Journey Builder Email Journey triggered to send when a Client completes a webform. There are some web call back fields that capture the window of time and date that they would like to be called back.

Within this Journey I'm looking at a requirement to dynamically add in an 'add to calendar link/button' to an email to prompt the client at the time that they have specified.

The only instructions that I seem to be able to find involve creating the calendar invitations for specific events For example:https://addtocalendar.com/

The reminders that I need to generate will be dynamic based on the date time that the customer selects. Has someone implemented before/is this possible? Are there any useful sites/docs I can read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newsletters, you can only use "Add to Calendar" links. On AddEvent.com you can find the "Direct URL Method" - it enables you to add dynamic "Add to Calendar" links in your newsletters/notification - and event attach event files if you use a Mail API like Mandrill. Take a look here: https://www.addevent.com/api/direct-url-method